# On groups with presentations $ \langle a,b,c\mid a^2=b^2=c^2=(ab)^p=(bc)^q=(ca)^r=(abc)^s=1\rangle $...

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-presentation, coxeter-groups

$$
\langle a,b,c\mid a^2=b^2=c^2=(ab)^p=(bc)^q=(ca)^r=1\rangle =\Delta(p,q,r)
$$
This is a presentation of a [triangle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group) $\Delta(p,q,r)$, a special kind of [Coxeter group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group).

**EDIT** In fact, these are called extended triangle groups, by G. Jones and D. Singerman in *Maps, hypermaps and triangle groups*...

What about the following presentation:
$$
\langle a,b,c\mid a^2=b^2=c^2=(ab)^p=(bc)^q=(ca)^r=(abc)^s=1\rangle 
$$
Do these groups have a name and where are they treated?

The presentation in question are motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1622906/19341) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1640803/19341)...

**ANOTHER EDIT**
if $p=q=r$ is prime and $s=1$ this is called triangular Fuchsian group [here](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2008/609425.pdf#page=5)...

Comment: Have you come across generalised triangle groups? What I call a triangle group is the group of transformations of the tiled plane (no reflections); Wikipedia calls these von Dyck groups. Such groups have presentation $\langle x, y, x; x^p, y^q, z^r, xyz\rangle$, and here $ab=x$, $bc=y$ and $ca=z$. A *generalised triangle group* is a group with presentation $\langle x, y, x; x^p, y^q, z^r, W(x, y, z)\rangle$. Fine and Rosenberger wrote a whole book motivated by these groups and their generalisations (one-relator products). Jim Howie has also written a lot about them.

Comment: @user1729 you mean $<x,y,{\bf z};\dots>$? Do you have some explicite references or links to them?

Comment: Yes, $x, y, z$. When I google the first link is to a paper of Jim Howie (http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~jim/preprint27.pdf). The references look extensive. I am pretty sure he gave a talk on these at a conference in 2012 I was at. The book of Fine and Rosenberger is "Algebraic generalizations of discrete groups: a path to combinatorial group theory through one-relator products".

Comment: @user1729 why not posting this as an answer...

Comment: Instead of editing this old post again, you might be better asking a new question about your new edit. If you think Derek Holt's answer is insufficient then you could consider asking on MathOverflow.

Comment: @user1729, sorry, and I just realised that Derek points out exactly what I edited...

Comment: @user1729 but you're right. I did: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3819674/19341

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't come across a name for this family in full generality, but the special case in which $p=2$ was defined and studied by Coxeter in his paper

H. S. M. Coxeter, The abstract groups $G^{ m, n, p}$, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 45 (1939),  73-150.

where (in your notation) the group is called $G^{q,r,s}$.

Also, when $s$ is even, your group has a subgroup of index $2$ with presentation $\langle x,y \mid x^p=y^q=(xy)^r=[x,y]^{s/2} \rangle$.

These groups were studied in the same paper by Coxeter, and denoted $(p,q,r;s/2)$.

Both of these families have been extensively studied since then, in particular concerning their finiteness. They are generally infinite for sufficiently large values of the parameters, and there is just a handful of remaining cases for which their finiteness is still unknown.

A few years ago Havas and I showed, using a big computer calculation, that $(2,3,13;4)$ is finite of order $358\,848\,921\,600$. So your group with $(p,q,r,s) = (2,3,13,8)$ has twice that order.

Comment: +1 great the paper is [available online](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1939-045-01/S0002-9947-1939-1501984-9/S0002-9947-1939-1501984-9.pdf) and for free

Comment: hmmm: when I replace $A,B,C$ in the definition of $G^{m,n,p}$ by $A=x/y, \; B=y/z,\; C=z/x$ and use that $x^2=y^2=z^2=1$ (so they are self-inverse) I get: $\langle (xy)^m=(yz)^n=(zx)^p=x^2=y^2=z^2=(\frac xy \frac yz \frac zx)^2=1 \rangle$, where the triple product is trivial. Now it looks just like the triangle group. What have I done (wrong)?

Comment: Maybe you are interested: The presentation in question are motivated by [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1622906/19341) and [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1640803/19341)...

Comment: Help you with what?