# general properties for Cayley graphs of hyperbolic triangle groups

Tags: reference-request, coxeter-groups, cayley-graphs

Is it possible to derive some general properties for [Cayley graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) of [hyperbolic triangle groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group), presented as
$$
\langle a,b,c | a^2=b^2=c^2=(ab)^p=(bc)^q=(ca)^r=1\rangle \text{, with } \frac1p+\frac1q+\frac1r<1
$$

Although I found [this](https://www.mathi.uni-heidelberg.de/%7Epozzetti/thesis/Vanmaele.pdf#page=26) and [this reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.0962.pdf), I don't have an idea, how to think about these graphs...

Since triangle groups relate to [tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane#General_triangle_domains) a lot, [this](https://bakingandmath.com/tag/cayley-graph/) looks helpful

> *Also, fun coincidence: if you create the dual tree to the tiling by putting a vertex inside each triangle and connecting two vertices by a line if one triangle is the image of another under one of the reflections, you get something that looks a lot like the Cayley graph of the reflection triangle group.  The only difference is that each edge needs to be two edges (like a little loop) to reflect that each generator has order 2.*

But despite the loopy edges, wouldn't that mean that my Cayley graph are infinite?

And looking at the list of tilings for example [$\Delta(4,4,4)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_tilings_in_hyperbolic_plane#(4_4_4)), I count 10 duals. Does this mean that these 10 are all valid Cayley graphs (maybe depending on the generators)?

Comment: The dual is a graph, not a tree. I also do not understand how you got 10 duals, there is only one tiling for each hyperbolic Coxeter group $W$ and one dual to this tiling. It is obviously infinite since  $W$ is infinite and it acts on the dual graph with finite vertex-stabilizers.

Comment: @MoisheKohan 1. The "tree"-statement is a citation. What's makes difference in your opinion? Trees are graphs in the end 2. When you uncollapse the table at the linked wiki page I see 10 tilings. This confused me as well. Which one is the one connected to the group? 3. I construct these groups from finite graphs (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1622906/19341)). I don't see why (in my case) the groups should be finite, when they act a finite set of vertices. Isn't that just permutations?

Comment: By definition, a tree is a simply-connected graph. I guess, whoever wrote "baking with math" web blog, did not know the difference.

Comment: My suggestion is to take a look at, say, "Office Hours with a Geometric Group Theorist." This probably will not answer your specific questions (I am not sure what they are), but will get you a better idea of the field than the sources you are currently reading.

Comment: @MoisheKohan right, I should have realised the tree thing myself. I'll get a hand on the book, but I don't see why these groups/graphs ([by my construction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1622906/19341)) need to be infinite. Are hyperbolic triangle groups necessarily infinite?

Comment: Yes, all hyperbolic triangle groups are infinite since they act cocompactly on the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see, so my graph-inspired representations represent finite subgroup of these infinite groups, right?

Comment: I do not know what are the "graph-inspired representations", but all the pictures of tilings you will find, show only a finite portion of an infinite tiling and, accordingly, only a finite part of the dual graph.

Comment: @MoisheKohan the one I gave here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622906/mapping-delta2-2-2-mapsto-delta4-4-2

Comment: I guess, you are describing a way to construct homomorphisms between Coxeter groups by changing labels. However, your old question was based on a wrong premise: The homomorphism should be in the opposite direction. It will be also sending a Euclidean triangle group to a finite group. One can use a similar construction to construct homomorphisms to finite groups from **some** hyperbolic triangle groups.

Comment: @Moishe from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Continuous_group_actions) "An action of a group G on a locally compact space X is cocompact if there exists a compact subset A of X such that GA = X. For a properly discontinuous action, cocompactness is equivalent to compactness of the quotient space X/G." What is the compact subset A in this case? Is it one single triangle, because G would (freely) generate the whole hyperbolic plane X from it?

Comment: Yes, it is the single triangle.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I hope you don't mind my beginners questions: 1. Since there are infinitely many points to turn the triangles, the group size is (countably?) infinite, right? 2. If I enumerate all the triangles, every group element permutes the triangles. Doesn't this give an infinite dimensional regular (no fixed points) representation of the group?

Comment: Yes on all three questions.