# finite groups are subgroups of the infinite one

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, infinite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Given an [hyperbolic triangle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group), presented as
$$
\langle a,b,c \mid a^2=b^2=c^2=(ab)^p=(bc)^q=(ca)^r=1\rangle \text{, with } \frac1p+\frac1q+\frac1r<1.  \tag1
$$

As pointed out in [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3803995/general-properties-for-cayley-graphs-of-hyperbolic-triangle-groups#comment7852502_3803995), these groups are infinite. But what if I'm able to construct finite groups that respect the same relations as given in $(1)$. An example, based on graphs, is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1622906/19341). Does this mean that

> the finite groups are subgroups of the infinite one?

Comment: If they satisfy the same relations, then they are *quotients* of the group given by the presentation. This is von Dyck’s Theorem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks, what does that mean for the the relation of Cayley graphs of the infinite and the finite one?

Comment: The same: it means the Cayley graphs are quotients of the Cayley graph of the hyperbolic triangle group (with the same generators).

Comment: If $p, q, r>6$ then your group contains an index-2 subgroup which satisfies the $C'(1/6)$ small cancellation condition (this is the subgroup of orientation-preserving transformations). The only finite-order subgroups of small cancellation groups are finite cyclic, and indeed they are precisely the conjugates of the "obvious" elements of finite order which you can see in the presentation. This is because small cancellation presentations satisfy a certain "asphericity" condition; the same property probably also holds for all orientation-preserving hyperbolic triangle groups. I cannot remember.

Comment: My point is: for large $p,q,r$ such presentations contain many finite quotients (this is easy to verify), but have very few finite subgroups. In particular every finite subgroup of the group you give contains a cyclic group of order $p$, $q$ or $r$, and which has index at most two.

Comment: Also, more hand-waving-ey, hyperbolic groups have only finitely many isomorphism classes of finite subgroups, while they have *lots* of quotients. I am unsure how to quantify "lots" at the moment, but there is stuff in Gromov's essay about torsion quotients of hyperbolic groups, and I cannot remember if this extends to finite images. Hmm...

Comment: Yes, it is a standard confusion of quotient groups and subgroups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem seems to be the common "are quotient groups the same as subgroups?" problem, as adding relators in corresponds to quotienting by the normal closure of those relators. If so, then the easiest counter-example which comes to mind is $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition. Here, every proper *quotient group* is finite cyclic, while every non-trivial *subgroup* is infinite cyclic. Therefore, the only group occuring as both a quotient group and a subgroup is the trivial group.

Okay, lets now take the question seriously. There *are* groups for which every quotient group occurs as a subgroup (e.g. finite cyclic groups), so the question asked here is not unreasonable, and possibly even interesting! The answer for hyperbolic triangle groups is:

> **No**. Every hyperbolic triangle group $\Delta(p, q, r)$ has finite quotient groups which are *not* isomorphic to subgroup of $\Delta(p, q, r)$.

A group $G$ is *residually finite* if for every non-trivial element $g\in G$ there exists a homomorphism $\phi_g:G\rightarrow H_g$ such that $g\not\in\ker(\phi_g)$ and $H_g$ is finite (equivalently, there exists a normal subgroup $N_g$ of finite index in $G$ such that $g\not\in N_g$). Triangle groups are residually finite, and the above result is in fact true for every residually finite hyperbolic group*.

*Proof.*
As hyperbolic triangle groups are infinite and residually finite, they have quotient groups of unbounded order (for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a quotient group of order greater than $n$). In particular, they have infinitely many isomorphism classes of finite quotient groups. On the other hand, hyperbolic groups have only finitely many conjugacy classes of finite subgroups; hence they have only finitely many isomorphism classes of finite subgroups. Therefore, there are more isomorphism classes of quotient groups than quotient groups, and the result follows. QED

We can actually say something concrete about the finite subgroups of these triangle groups $\Delta(p,q,r)$ when $p, q, r>6$**. Here, the presentation $\Delta_o(p,q,r)=\langle x, y, z\mid x^p, y^q, z^r, xyz\rangle$ defines an index-two subgroup (this is the group of orientation-preserving symmetries, and is often itself referred to as a "triangle group"). We can then cancel the $z$-generator to get the presentation $\langle x, y\mid x^p, y^q, (xy)^r\rangle$, which satisfies the $C'(1/6)$ [small cancellation condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_cancellation_theory). Therefore, by results from small cancellation theory (see previous link), every finite subgroup is cyclic, and indeed conjugate to a subgroup of one of the subgroups $\langle x\rangle$, $\langle y\rangle$ or $\langle z\rangle$. Hence, every finite subgroup of $\Delta(p,q,r)$ contains one such subgroup of finite index. So, for example, the largest possible order of a finite subgroup of $\Delta(p,q,r)$ is $\max(2p, 2q, 2r)$.

*The point about residual finiteness underlies JCAA's now-deleted partial answer. The earliest citation I can find for residual finiteness of these triangle groups actually proves a strictly stronger property called LERF: Scott, Peter. "Subgroups of surface groups are almost geometric." Journal of the London Mathematical Society 2.3 (1978): 555-565.

**The same result holds without the restriction of $p,q,r>6$, using the theory of [Fuschsian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchsian_group), but properly working out how the bits of this theory fit together is not a rabbit hole I wish to crawl down today.

Comment: +1 thanks, but is it not $\Delta_o(p,q,r)=\langle a, b, c\mid (ab)^p, (bc)^q, (ca)^r, abc\rangle$ as in my original post. Is it just a relabelling. BTW: The restriction of $p,q,r>6$ is fine with me; I expect even larger values, since it is related to cycles in bicubic graphs. Nevertheless the Fuchsian approach is intersting to me as well, if this could give some other representations of my groups...

Comment: @draks... The $a, b, c$ in $\Delta_0$ are *different* elements from the $a, b, c$ in $\Delta$. This was an unfortunate typo. I have altered the generators of $\Delta_0$ to be $x, y, z$, where indeed $x=ab$, $y=bc$ and $z=ca$. (But the presentation in your comment is incorrect. Its generators should be $ab, bc, ca$ *not* $a,b, c$. But $ab, bc, ca$ are not letters, which is why we use $x,y,z$ instead.)